# I cannot install Amazon Inspector

Tags: amazon-web-services, redhat, oraclelinux, amazon-inspector

When I executed the "Run Command" with the "AmazonInspector-ManageAWSAgent
" Document, The output gives me this error:

```
Failed to find an inspector agent package for this OS:ol-5.4..
```

The OS version of the server is Oracle Linux Server (based from Red Hat Linux 7.9)

How can I upgrade the "OS:ol-5.4 to 7"?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem. Turns out Inspector agent isn't supported on Amazon Linux 2022 yet. Not sure if that's your problem too:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/inspector/v1/userguide/inspector_supported_os_regions.html